# Quick android & phonegap bundler

Tags: android, cordova

I am looking for a utility that would quickly bundle up a phonegap app for android from an html directory. Perhaps something that would read some config.json file in that directory to automatically take care of all the configurations.

Basically I am looking to avoid doing all the setup of eclipse just to wrap my html5 app which already works fine on android through the browser.

Anyone have any good tricks or tools that can shortcut the whole process to something close to what I am dreaming about? I would love something where in 10 minutes I can have everything ready to deploy to the marketplace.

Comment: I've never heard of one, but I don't do much digging for info on the write once deploy everywhere platforms like phonegap. Honestly though I think creating the native apk yourself and just using a WebView to display your html stuff would be easier than you think. I would also advice against referring to yourself as "lazy programmer that doesn't want to have to learn" when asking for help from others. People tend to be far more willing to help if you are willing to put forth the effort to help yourself too.

Comment: Also this page on the phonegap forums seems to indicate that it will already output an apk file for you: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/is_the_output_from_phonegap_build_ready_for_publishing_to_google_market?from_gsfn=true    It is however up to you to generate your own signature keys (which eclipse will make much easier than using the commandline tools that come with SDK IMO) so that your app is signed with a release key and not the debug key. It must not be signed with the debug key in order to be uploaded to the market.

Comment: @Tim - I think the rest of the sentence matters. I am not interested in the spending a few hours learning to set up an IDE that I never have any intention on using. I am looking for a more automated way to just get my code bundled. I am working off of this concept: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LazinessImpatienceHubris and hoping someone else was lazy enough to just write something so they wouldn't have to do it anymore. But, you make a good point, and I reworded it.

Comment: That is a good read, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

One option is [AppLaud Cloud](http://applaudcloud.com/). Note, that it is still in alpha.

With AppLaud Cloud, you could create a Base App and then replace the contents of the assets/www directory with your html5 app.

You can emulate the app with the built-in Emulator, debug the app on device with Weinre, and build for deployment to the market.

Caveat: I'm the creator of AppLaudCloud.

Comment: Nothing wrong with noting a product if it's relevant and answers the question or helps the user *(imho)*. But to be fair and transparent it should also be mentioned that you are the founder of that company *(according to your profile and the website)*.

Answer (score 1):

Dreamweaver 5.5 has a function like the one you are looking for. I played with it briefly and is ok. More info here: http://blogs.nitobi.com/andre/index.php/2011/04/12/adobe-dreamweaver-5-5-supports-phonegap/

The plus: works with ios also(if you're on mac)

The minus: quite expensive stuff...

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the new (undocumented) command line tools in the PhoneGap Android source. There is a command for creating a new app (https://github.com/callback/callback-android/tree/master/bin) and in the new app folder there is a command for debugging the app (on emulator or device).

You could also check out https://github.com/brianleroux/cordova which is a prototype for the command line tools that are now in the platform specific PhoneGap repos on github.

Going forward there will be more work done on Cordova but probably as an official PhoneGap repo / binary distribution.